# no recursion error while importing file infinitely times

Tags: python

**Why doesn't recursion happen when doing this:**

there are two .py files in same folder: *A.py* and *B.py*

*A.py*'s code:
`import B` (1 line)

*B.py*'s code:
`import A` (1 line)

when executing *A.py* no recursion (*error*) happens

**Why I expect it to happen**
whenever importing .py file, its code is executed
so executing A, it imports B
then executing B, imports A
which, in return, again executes A

and that, at first glimpse should be infinite recursion

P.S. working in python 3 so not sure if it happens in 2

Comment: `import` doesn't mean "run this thing".